# Print out properties that are not equal between two objects

Tags: swift

Say I have a `User` class with three properties: `name`, `email`, and `fruits`. What's the most efficient way to determine the differences, and print them out in a dictionary alongside the property name?:

```swift
struct User: Equatable {
    let name: String
    let email: String
    let fruits: [Fruit]
}

// Old user
let user = User(name: "Jane", email:"ja@ne.com", fruits: [.banana, .apple])

// Updated user
let updatedUser = User(name: user.name, email: user.email, fruits: [.apple, .peach])

// Looking for help writing a function that can efficiently find the changes + format them into a dictionary for Firebase etc:
let updatedProperties = updatesBetween(old: user, new: updatedUser)

// Output:
//["fruits": ["apple", "peach"]]
```

Comment: I don't think there is any more efficient way than comparing property by property, have you tried that?

Answer (score -1):

Take advantage of the fact that these objects are `Equatable` and check for their equality right off the bat before proceeding, and then go property by property and look for differences. Keep in mind that arrays care about order so `[.apple, .banana]` will be different from `[.banana, .apple]`. If you don't care about order then just sort them both before comparing (this may require additional steps depending on the contents of the array). You can also consider translating the arrays into sets before comparing (if the arrays don't contain duplicates).

```
func getDifferencesBetween(old: User, new: User) -> [String: Any] {
    guard old != new else {
        return [:]
    }
    var differences: [String: Any] = [:]
    
    if old.name != new.name {
        differences["name"] = new.name
    }
    if old.email != new.email {
        differences["email"] = new.email
    }
    if old.fruits != new.fruits {
        differences["fruits"] = new.fruits
    }
    return differences
}
```